# Envers query for revisions of multiple entities

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

We want to show the revisions of multiple entities in one pageable list. The AuditQuery only supports querying single entities like in the example below.

```
  final AuditQuery documentQuery = auditReader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(Component.class, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(component.getId()))
    .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
    .setMaxResults(10)
    .setFirstResult(0);
```

What we actually want is a query implementation which looks like the following:

```
  final AuditQuery documentQuery = auditReader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntities(Component.class, Type.class, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(Component.class, component.getId()))
    .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(Type.class, type.getId()))
    .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
    .setMaxResults(10)
    .setFirstResult(0);
```

To make this more clear - I simply want to query multiple entities with the AuditQuery to get multiple revisions from different entities.

The relationship between the Component and Type is Many To One

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type")
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.AUDITED)
public class Type extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable,Externalized {

// ...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "type")
@Audited(targetAuditMode = AUDITED)
private Set<Component> components = new HashSet<>();

// ... 

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "component")
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.AUDITED)
public class Component extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable, Externalized {

// ...

@ManyToOne
@Audited(targetAuditMode = AUDITED)
private Type type;

// ...

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance - Simon

Comment: Is there any relationship between `Cmoponent` and `Type` or are these completely separate unrelated entity types in your object model?

Comment: There is a relation. I updated the question. Thanks for having a look at it!

Comment: Hello @SimonH we are facing the same issue.
Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Sorry. We didn't find a solution.